# How to read in .ascii file and convert? (Python)

Tags: python, excel

I have some .ascii files. the first few lines, when opened in Excel, look like this:

```
>ETASAsciiItemFile  record  CrLf    Tab
>sampleCount    22327       
>time   sys_inp_amb_temp_degc\CCP:1     
>f8 f4      
>s  °C      
>0,454984023542835  235,938     
>0,671164096921757  235,938
```

I need to be able to supply "normal" looking numbers. Converting to a csv is ideal.

Here's what I have - I am

```
app = QApplication( sys.argv )
fname1 = unicode( QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() )
app.quit

csv1_array = []
with open(fname1,'rb') as csv1_doc:
    csv1_array += csv.reader(csv1_doc)

path_plus_title1 = (fname1.strip('.ascii')) +'.csv'

with open(path_plus_title1, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(csv1_array)
```

I know, I should be putting these bits into functions, and I will. I was just trying to do it quick n dirty.

Here is how my output currently looks:

```
>"ETASAsciiItemFile record  CrLf    Tab"        
>"sampleCount   22327          "        
>"time  sys_inp_amb_temp_degc\CCP:1 "       
>"f8    f4  "       
>"s ""°C""  "       
>0  "454984023542835    23" "5938   "
>0  "671164096921757    23" "5938   "
```

- clearly, since I'm telling it to open it as if it's unicode, that's a problem. It rejects ASCII as an option, though.
- Also, it's deciding that those commas are delimiters. Also a problem.

Any thoughts? Excel options instead of Python options are totally welcome.

Comment: The `°` symbol isn't part of ASCII. And it's really hard to determine what you're asking here.

Comment: All I know about the files is that their extension is .ascii - when I told it to open with Excel, that's how they look. I need to figure out what these values really are....

Comment: I figured it out, I think. It looks like these are really .txt files and the ,s are .s - but Excel doesn't understand. I am now opening in WordPad and replacing the commas with periods.

Answer (score 1):

That unicode is just for the file name. It does nothing to the contents of the file.

You are reading and writing files as binary. It is not clear from the question if this is what you really want.

There is a somewhat sneaky bug on this line:

```
path_plus_title1 = (fname1.strip('.ascii')) +'.csv'
```

`strip()` doesn't do what you think it does. It strips all characters at the end of the string that are in the set you are asking to remove. So if `fname1` is for example `'isac.ascii'`, then that `strip()` will produce empty string!

Finally, and this is where I am really guessing since it is not clear from your question, you would want to convert "0,671164096921757" into "0.671164096921757". In other words, your data was produced in locale that used commas as decimal separator, but you want to convert it into locale where dot is used as decimal separator.

The first change you probably want to put in your reading code is to specify the delimiter. By default it is the comma, which is breaking your data into different cells.

There is one sure way of converting the commas, and another potential way which I haven't tested. The sure way is to add code in between reading and writing the data where you inspect the data you have in memory, recognize the pattern of digits + comma + digits and convert it yourself.

The other potential way could be to change your locale to one where comma is decimal separator, read the data in, change locale to where dot is separator, and write out. But like I said, I have never tried this so I don't know if this would work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that bug out! Basically, the only info I had about the format of the info was that the files I was given ended in ".ascii". When I (finally) opened them in WordPad, I discovered the , vs. decimal problem, which was easy enough to fix without code.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's TextToColumns allows you to specify the thousands separator and the decimal character.  I cannot tell from your question exactly how you want the results.  It might be as simple as opening (or importing) the ASCII file in Excel (whichever way brings up the texttocolumns wizard, and specifying your requirements.

Also, it's a little hard to write an input routine, without knowing what your source data looks like.  You've only shown what it looks like in Excel; not the original file.

Here is a VBA macro that allows you to select a file (filtering the files so you only see those with .ascii file type; it then reads the file line-by-line, stripping off the leading ">" (which you can omit if that is not necessary).  It then splits the file by the space character, after specifying the thousands and decimal separators.  In the VBA routine, you can specify a Destination for the data, which I did.

```
Option Explicit
'Could use late-binding for easier portability
'    Early binding --> Intellisense help
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub GetASCIIFile()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim S As String

'set rData to first cell for output
Set rData = Range("A1")

'Get File Path
sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("ASCII Files (*.ascii), *.ascii")

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath, ForReading)

Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream = True
    S = TS.ReadLine

    'Remove leading > if present
    If Left(S, 1) = ">" Then S = Mid(S, 2)

    'Write into cell
    rData = S
    Set rData = rData(2, 1)
Loop

'Split the data on <space>

With Range("a2", Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp))
    .TextToColumns Destination:=[b2], DataType:=xlDelimited, consecutivedelimiter:=True, _
    Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=True, other:=False, _
    DecimalSeparator:=",", ThousandsSeparator:="."

End With

End Sub
```